# Django Different form validation when adding and changing instance

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

My question is that can we perform different form validation on the same form based on different action, such as adding or changing.

Say I have a model which has a field named 'type'. And 'type' is an enum field whose choices are 'Manual' and 'Auto'. When adding a new instance, I don't want the user able to set 'type' to 'Auto'. However, the user would view and modify the instance whose 'type' is 'Auto'.

Maybe I don't need validation to do this. So if there is any other option, I' like to hear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Using anything over 1.3 will make this a breeze when using Class Based Views. Where you would have a `CreateView` and a `EditView` where the `CreateView` would handle the new instances and the `EditView` would handle the editing and updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the model:

```
class Spam(models.Model):
    foo_type = models.WhateverFieldType(editable=False, choices=FOO_TYPE_CHOICES)
    # ... other fields
```

Use this form (which excludes the `foo_type` field (disallows editing that field using the form and also disables validation of the field - it's basically, "here, edit anything on this `Spam` instance except `foo_type`"):

```
class SpamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('foo_type',)
```

Then, create a subclass of `UpdateView` and one of `ListView` and update the queryset to include only users who's `tye_type` is set to `Auto`.

```
class SpamUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SpamUpdateView, self).get_queryset().filter(foo_type=FOO_TYPE_AUTO)

class SpamListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SpamListView, self).get_queryset().filter(foo_type=FOO_TYPE_AUTO)
```